# Querytable was workin but just stopped

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

this code worked up to a week ago and then decided not to any help much appreciated the spreadsheet has not changed and neither has the csv file to be imported.

I have listed the code below the err message for the file import is 1004 file does not exist but the file is in the correct directory

```
Sub ImportCSV(SheetName As String, FiletoImport As String)

On Error GoTo errorhandler


Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String, msgtext As String, response

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

CreateSheet:

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)

On Error GoTo importerror

' strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please selec text file...")
 With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FiletoImport, _
 Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
 '    .Refresh
 End With

Select Case SheetName

    Case "POData"

            Call ProcessPOData

    Case "SOData"

        Call ProcessSOData
        Call DeleteRows

    Case "AvgSales"

        Call CreateAvgSales

End Select

Exit Sub

errorhandler:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Error(Err)
    Resume CreateSheet

importerror:

MsgBox Err & ": " & Error(Err)
msgtext = "Failed to Import " & FiletoImport
response = MsgBox(msgtext, vbCritical, "Import File Failed")





 End Sub
```

Comment: you won't be happy with my comment but ... this is the reason I never use QueryTables to retrieve any external data but I use ADO which I can rely on all the time...

Comment: Try commenting out the `On Error GoTo errorhandler` to make sure the error is really coming from where you think it is.